# tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for 'max_pooling2d_1/MaxPool'

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I am trying to implement a neural network used for image classification with Keras and Tensorflow, according to the tutorial [from here](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html).

I added the following code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(3, 150, 150)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
```

However, the problem is that I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py", line 671, in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl
16.4s
3
    input_tensors_as_shapes, status)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 89, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for 'max_pooling2d_1/MaxPool' (op: 'MaxPool') with input shapes: [?,1,148,32].

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../src/script.py", line 49, in <module>
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Keras-2.0.5-py3.6.egg/keras/models.py", line 469, in add
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Keras-2.0.5-py3.6.egg/keras/engine/topology.py", line 596, in __call__
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Keras-2.0.5-py3.6.egg/keras/layers/pooling.py", line 154, in call
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Keras-2.0.5-py3.6.egg/keras/layers/pooling.py", line 217, in _pooling_function
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Keras-2.0.5-py3.6.egg/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 3378, in pool2d
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 1769, in max_pool
16.4s
4
    name=name)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_nn_ops.py", line 1605, in _max_pool
    data_format=data_format, name=name)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 767, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2508, in create_op
    set_shapes_for_outputs(ret)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1873, in set_shapes_for_outputs
    shapes = shape_func(op)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1823, in call_with_requiring
    return call_cpp_shape_fn(op, require_shape_fn=True)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py", line 610, in call_cpp_shape_fn
    debug_python_shape_fn, require_shape_fn)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py", line 676, in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl
    raise ValueError(err.message)
ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for 'max_pooling2d_1/MaxPool' (op: 'MaxPool') with input shapes: [?,1,148,32].
```

After that, I looked [at a possible answer](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/3945) and I changed the last line to this:

```
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), dim_ordering="tf"))
```

But after this change I getting the same error.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The code you provided was written with assuming that your backend is `Theano`. In case of `Tensorflow` you should change your input to have shape `(width, height, channels)` so you should change this line:

```
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(150, 150, 3)))
```

Your problem comes from that after the convolution (with `valid` padding) your output has shape`(1, 148, 32)` so it's impossible to apply `MaxPooling2D` with stride `(2, 2)` which is a default value.

Comment: But maxpooling shouldn't be done on the output, right? It should only be done on some hidden layers, correct? So how could I change to code to make this work?

Comment: By `output` I meant `output` from a first convolutional layer.

Comment: Why does it have that shape? Nowhere in the code do I specify `(1, 148, 32)`.

Comment: I tried changing the padding to this: `model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(3, 150, 150), padding='SAME'))` but I get the same error.

Comment: You need to change `channel_ordering` in `keras.json`.